# Decide function call on variable-pointer to base class

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the following code. I have a base class and a derived class which I can't modify. And i have a vector in which I store some pointers to the base class.

Now when I iterate over the vector it should call the right void Function depending on the typ of the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//base and a can't be modified, because they are in a library
class base
{
virtual ~base(){};
};

class a : public base
{
virtual ~a(){};
};

void Funktion(base* variable)
{
    cout << "base" << endl;
}
void Funktion(a* variable)
{
    cout << "a" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<base*> list;
    list.push_back(new a());
    list.push_back(new base());

    for each (base* var in list)
        Funktion(var);
}
```

In this example it should output:

```
a
base
```

But it outputs:

```
base
base
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Regards Stefan

Edit: insert virtual destructor

Comment: Your class hierarchy isn't polymorphic (the base has not virtual functions), so you cannot solve this without changing your code.

Comment: In case of polymorphic code you would need a virtual function or a visitor-like pattern (depending on the circumstances) to get this job done.

Comment: To be sure, your code has a gaping, unfixable memory leak: You can never ever delete the objects pointed to by the elements of the vector because the base class doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @pasztorpisti RTTI is another possibility, but those listed by you are surely nicer

Comment: @Paranaix Sometimes when the code/source isn't yours then unfortunately you have to fallback to RTTI. +1

Comment: Both classes have a virtual destructor. I have just simplified the code example a little and have not thought that this is important.

Comment: @user3376892 If your base class has a virtual destructor then it is inherited by all direct/indirect descendants, no need to explicitly declare it in `a`. You need the virtual destructor only if you delete the instances of the class by deleting a base class pointer. You will need the virtual destructor here but your deleter code is missing -> the previously mentioned leaks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use virtual functions. You can also use `std::unique_ptr` to avoid memory leaks, i.e.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    base() { }
    virtual ~base() { }
    virtual void function() { std::cout << "base\n"; }
};
class a : public base
{
public:
    a() { }
    ~a() { }
    virtual void function() { std::cout << "a\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> list;
    list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<base>(new a()));
    list.push_back(std::unique_ptr<base>(new base()));

    for (const auto& e : list)
    {
        e->function();
    }
}
```

The other is to attempt a `dynamic_cast` for your derived object.

```
    a* ptr = dynamic_cast<a*>(e.get());
    if (ptr)
        funktion(ptr);
    else
        funktion(e.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading is done at compile time, whereas what you are wanting here is a runtime choice between the two functions.  So that will mean using virtual methods for polymorphism, or if that isn't going to be possible, then to query the runtime type information directly, such as with dynamic_cast<>

If the existing library turns out to be such a poor fit to your object oriented design, it may work out to write an object oriented wrapper to it